# How to change image and text at the same time on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dropdown

I'm trying to change my text and image on click ***(mobile only)*** but it's not working. Only the image can be changed with the function I wrote. Could anyone help me with that, please?
Here is the live code: https://codepen.io/oleanderek/pen/OdNzME

```
    document.querySelectorAll(".nav__label").forEach((el) => {
    el.addEventListener('click', changeArrow);
  el.addEventListener('click', changeText);
});

function changeArrow() {
    var arrow = this.getElementsByClassName('arrow')[0];

    if (arrow.classList.contains("down-arrow")) {
        arrow.classList.remove("down-arrow");
        arrow.classList.add("up-arrow");
    } else if (arrow.classList.contains("up-arrow")) {
        arrow.classList.remove("up-arrow");
        arrow.classList.add("down-arrow");
    }
}

function changeText() {
    var changeText = this.getElementsByClassName('showText')[0];

    if (changeText.classList.contains("showText")) {
        arrow.classList.remove("showText");
        arrow.classList.add("hideText");
    } else if (changeText.classList.contains("hideText")) {
        arrow.classList.remove("hideText");
        arrow.classList.add("showText");
    }
}
```

Comment: It is the same event. So just use a single callback function that performs both.

Comment: I was adding && inside the if statement but it didn't work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you delete the class to change, the variable you define remains undefined. Therefore, you must define a class that you will not change. I added `newClass` This works fine.

HTML

```
 <p class="newClass showText">.</p>
```

Javascript

```
   document.querySelectorAll(".nav__label").forEach((el) => {
    el.addEventListener('click', changeArrow);
  el.addEventListener('click', changeText);
});

function changeArrow() {
    var arrow = this.getElementsByClassName('arrow')[0];

    if (arrow.classList.contains("down-arrow")) {
        arrow.classList.remove("down-arrow");
        arrow.classList.add("up-arrow");
    } else if (arrow.classList.contains("up-arrow")) {
        arrow.classList.remove("up-arrow");
        arrow.classList.add("down-arrow");
    }
}

function changeText() {
    var changeText = document.querySelector(".newClass");

    if (changeText.classList.contains("showText")) {
        changeText.classList.remove("showText");
        changeText.classList.add("hideText");
    } else if (changeText.classList.contains("hideText")) {
        changeText.classList.remove("hideText");
        changeText.classList.add("showText");
    }
}
```